# Datatype for the number

Tags: java, algebraic-data-types

How should I change the geometry datatype to String in Java?

Comment: Well seeing as that "number" won't fit in any numeric type, you need to use either an array or a String.

Comment: What operations do you want to do with it?

Comment: Could you please reformat your question to remove many repeating characters that has not any meaning?

Comment: With an example of code that utilize `Base64Encoder` to encode a string would be worth for [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Thanks Roman. Can you provide me some info on working to convert the geometry datatype to String in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BigInteger`.

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("01060000000100000...", 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `BigInteger`. It has a constructor taking a String and a radix as an argument.

So:

```
new BigInteger(theString, 16);
```